# How to efficiently structure a python script intended to be run in parts from the command line?

Tags: python, command-line, module

Suppose I have a script like so:

```
import argparse

def set_up():
    
    # Code that takes a while to run
    
    initial_number = 5
    
    return initial_number

def add_n(initial_number, n):
    
    # Code that doesn't take so long 
    
    result = initial_number + n
    
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("n", help="number to add")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    n = int(args.n)
    
    initial_number = set_up()
    
    result = add_n(initial_number, n)
    
    print(result)
```

The idea is the run it from the command line using the command (for example):

`python foo.py 3`

Which returns `8`. All good so far. My thing is that I want to be able to call the script again after (e.g., say, `python foo.py 1` to return `6`) **without re-running** the `set_up` method.

In this illustrative example it doesn't matter, but for my purposes the `set_up` method takes quite a while to run. What I'd like is to be able to run the setup only once, and then to run the `add_n` method multiple times. Is this possible? If so, how can it be done? Otherwise, is there another approach to this type of requirement? Should I be thinking about the process differently? Ultimately the question is how to structure a script that has a heavy "loading" phase at the beginning that is only performed once.

Comment: That depends, at least in part, on what `setup` does.

Comment: Bit complicated to write answer, but, if the computations in `set_up` are dependent on external variables and take a long time, I’ve found that Redis caching - if you have Redis running anyway - can be helpful.  It lapses automatically after a time delay you decide, it’s fast and you can add an extra option to refresh.

Answer (score 2):

I see two solutions:

1. you store the output of the setup somewhere. and in the setup function you check for that stored output. If it exists, no need to do the heavy computation again. You can use a json, a text file or even a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).
2. You never leave the script. When the user launches the script, it runs the set up functions and then waits for user input. without leaving the python code. You can use a "while" loop, show some options to the user (example: 1) add a value 2) quit) and read the user input with [input built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input)

ps: not answering your question, you can use [fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire) library to replace argparse, it is more user friendly and easier to use.